# JQuery removeAttr and attr

Tags: jquery, attr

In this program I need to disable Html Button when checkbox is not selected. Button should be enable only if checkbox is selected. Im using Jquery version 1.8.3. However in this program swapping between enable and disable not working as I expected.

//------ HTML

```
    <body>
Some agreement here
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
</p>
<input type="button" value="Continue" disabled="disabled" id="continue"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/class.js"></script>  
</body>
```

//------JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#agree').change(function(){
        state = $(this).attr('value');
        if(state == 'on'){
            $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else if(state == ''){
            $('#continue').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You say "not working as I expected" - what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#agree').change(function(){
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked')
        if(checked){
            $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
            $('#continue').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

See [**this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5SNrW/)

In summary, you're checking for the **value** of `#agree`, which isn't set at any point. `prop()` is a better way to determine if a checkbox is checked. `prop()` will either return `true` or `false`, making things much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Is this compatible with version 1.8

Comment: It is. If you check out [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SNrW/), you'll see in the sidebar to the left that I used jQuery version 1.8.3.

Answer (score 2):

For `disabled` (and `checked`), you should instead use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#continue").prop("disabled",true);
```

Although it would help if you let us know what exactly isn't working as expected

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#agree').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
            $('#continue').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx lot for your solution. This is also correct solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The disabled attribute doesn't need a `="disabled"` after it. Just do:

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" disabled />
```

And you should be using `.prop('disabled', true)` instead anyways. And the `.removeProp()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#agree').click(function(){
           $("#continue").attr("disabled", !this.checked);

        });
    });
```

I hope this should help.
see in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/VPUfX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be use `this.checked` or use `$(this).is(":checked")` along with `prop` to manipulate the `input:button` :

```
 $('#agree').change(function () {
     $("#continue").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));
     //$("#continue").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
 });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/p9u7Y/